# Wonderful time at 4a.m. in the morning with Makefiles

Tags: makefile

```
CFLAGS = -Wall

libs = evento.h

main:  main.c $(libs)
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o main main.c $(libs)
```

I have this makefile and work, the problem is that i need to make that evento.h comes from a folder called /include inside the project folder and create another one with the name /lib with the file libeventos.a inside of it. I have read a lot of tutorials but i really dont understand.

Comment: Your makefile builds a program called main. What source builds the library? Is it main.c that is used to build the library?

Comment: the idea is to generate it with -o but i have no idea why is not working when we try to add them

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6U82puVw
my idea is to do something like this

Comment: Let me clarify. You have files in some directory and you want to generate to files: include/evento.h and lib/libevento.so. Or you have include/evento.h amd lib/libeveto.so and you want to use it to builld your main?

Comment: the builded main must use libevento.a to compile it cause i cant compile directly from the source code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the directory `main.c` is in has sub-directories `include` and `lib`. 
Note that "gcc" in the makefile is preceded by a TAB character.

main.c links in the library libevento.a.

main.c has a dependency ./include/evento.h

```
FLAGS = -Wall
CFLAGS=-I../include $(FLAGS)

main:  main.c ./include/evento.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o main main.c -L./lib -levento
```